# React / Ionic : Invalid hook call problem (use of history for redirections)

Tags: react-native, ionic-framework, events, routes, react-hooks

I am trying to redirect users using a click event and history to this route "/tab1".
I get an invalid hook call problem. I've tried to move it out but nothing seems to work.

Please help !
Thanks !

**The code :**

```
export class Tab2 extends Component {
  
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    
    this.playVideo = this.playVideo.bind(this)
  }
  
  playVideo() {
    // THE PROBLEM
    const history = useHistory();
    // NEED SOME REDIRECTION ON CLICK HERE
    history.push("/tab1")
  }
  
  render() {
    
    return (
      <IonPage>
        <IonHeader>
          <IonToolbar>
            <IonTitle>Tab 2</IonTitle>
          </IonToolbar>
        </IonHeader>
        <IonContent>
          <IonHeader collapse="condense">
            <IonToolbar>
              <IonTitle size="large">Tab 2</IonTitle>
            </IonToolbar>
          </IonHeader>
          <IonButton onClick={this.playVideo}>This is a play button</IonButton>
        </IonContent>
      </IonPage>
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can only use hooks in functional components

```
export const Tab2 =() =>  {
  
  const history = useHistory();

  const playVideo =()=> {
    history.push("/tab1")
  }
    
    return (
      <IonPage>
        <IonHeader>
          <IonToolbar>
            <IonTitle>Tab 2</IonTitle>
          </IonToolbar>
        </IonHeader>
        <IonContent>
          <IonHeader collapse="condense">
            <IonToolbar>
              <IonTitle size="large">Tab 2</IonTitle>
            </IonToolbar>
          </IonHeader>
          <IonButton onClick={()=>playVideo()}>This is a play button</IonButton>
        </IonContent>
      </IonPage>
    );
};
```

Comment: I see I was using a class component instead of functional component. It worked like magic ! thanks for the help !